# How do I drag and drop files into an application?

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

I've seen this done in Borland's [Turbo C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_C++) environment, but I'm not sure how to go about it for a C# application I'm working on. Are there best practices or gotchas to look out for?

Comment: Do you mean drag and drop in a C# Application or into the C# IDE?

Comment: Of cource, C# Application. He want to make his application drag&drop friendly.

Comment: @VenkateshKumar how is `ChangeWindowMessageFilter (0x0049, MSGFLT_ADD);` supposed to help in C#?

Answer (score 553):

Some sample code:

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.AllowDrop = true;
      this.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(Form1_DragEnter);
      this.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(Form1_DragDrop);
    }

    void Form1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
      if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop)) e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }

    void Form1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
      string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
      foreach (string file in files) Console.WriteLine(file);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Disclaimer : it may not work in debug if you run Visual Studio as an admin in Windows 7, or if you run your program as an admin. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833709/c-sharp-drag-drop-does-not-work-on-windows-7)

Comment: @Burnsys if you have the filepath from the drag operation, then you can read using `io.File`

Comment: Shouldn't the class be a sealed class to avoid making a virtual call on the `this.AllowDrop`?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119506/virtual-member-call-in-a-constructor

Comment: Ugh, no.  Set the AllowDrop property to True in the designer and reason it out from there.

Comment: Is the `(string[])` cast safe for any `FileDrop`-formatted drop?  That is, is it possible to generate a `FileDrop` that will cause an illegal cast exception to `string[]`?  I'm having trouble figuring that out from [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6a9edsb(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Great code snippet. I had a program that opened the files using dialog, and it was easy to add this feature in, and to make the adjustments so it worked just like dialog open but with drag and drop.

Comment: Works in WPF, too except the DragDrop event is named "Drop"

Comment: What is the difference between `Enter` and `Drop` here?

Comment: @Childishforlife Enter is when you hold the mouse button and Enter it into control, still holding and Drop is the moment when you let the mouse button go.

Answer (score 162):

Be aware of windows vista/windows 7 security rights - if you are running Visual Studio as administrator, you will not be able to drag files from a non-administrator explorer window into your program when you run it from within visual studio. The drag related events will not even fire!

Comment: @Wayne Uroda: I thought my code wasn't working - heck it was giving me a big "No symbol" like this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:ProhibitionSign2.svg . Then I saw this answer and ran VS as a non-admin and presto it works! Thanks a million.

Comment: Can't thank you enough for this, I would have given up unless I happened to find this post! It's as valid in Windows 10 in 2017 as it was when you wrote it.

Comment: Ok but what can we do? It is illogical? What if my program needs admin rights?

Comment: @MericOzcan does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833709/c-sharp-drag-drop-does-not-work-on-windows-7 ?

Comment: @WayneUroda I changed my program, now it selects files from path.

Answer (score 52):

In Windows Forms, set the control's AllowDrop property, then listen for DragEnter event and DragDrop event.

When the `DragEnter` event fires, set the argument's `AllowedEffect` to something other than none (e.g. `e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move`).

When the `DragDrop` event fires, you'll get a list of strings. Each string is the full path to the file being dropped.

Answer (score 17):

You need to be aware of a gotcha. Any class that you pass around as the [DataObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dataobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the drag/drop operation has to be Serializable. So if you try and pass an object, and it is not working, ensure it can be serialized as that is almost certainly the problem. This has caught me out a couple of times!

Answer (score 14):

Yet another gotcha:

The framework code that calls the Drag-events swallow all exceptions. You might think your event code is running smoothly, while it is gushing exceptions all over the place. You can't see them because the framework steals them.

That's why I always put a try/catch in these event handlers, just so I know if they throw any exceptions. I usually put a Debugger.Break(); in the catch part.

Before release, after testing, if everything seems to behave, I remove or replace these with real exception handling.

Answer (score 10):

Here is something I used  to drop files and/or folders full of files. In my case I was filtering for `*.dwg` files only and chose to include all subfolders.

`fileList` is an `IEnumerable` or similar In my case was bound to a WPF control...

```cs
var fileList = (IList)FileList.ItemsSource;
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19954958/492 for details of that trick.

The drop Handler ...

```cs
  private void FileList_OnDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
  {
    var dropped = ((string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop));
    var files = dropped.ToList();

    if (!files.Any())
      return;

    foreach (string drop in dropped)
      if (Directory.Exists(drop))
        files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(drop, "*.dwg", SearchOption.AllDirectories));

    foreach (string file in files)
    {
      if (!fileList.Contains(file) && file.ToLower().EndsWith(".dwg"))
        fileList.Add(file);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 9):

Another common gotcha is thinking you can ignore the Form DragOver (or DragEnter) events. I typically use the Form's DragOver event to set the AllowedEffect, and then a specific control's DragDrop event to handle the dropped data.

Answer (score 5):

The solution of Judah Himango and Hans Passant is available in the Designer (I am currently using VS2015):

[image]

[image]

Comment: This wont work until you also use DragEnter and then set e.Effect = DragDropEfects.Move or something like that. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can implement Drag&Drop in WinForms and WPF.

- WinForm (Drag from app window)

You should add mousemove event:

```
private void YourElementControl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)

    {
     ...
         if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
         {
                 DoDragDrop(new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, new string[] { PathToFirstFile,PathToTheNextOne }), DragDropEffects.Move);
         }
     ...
    }
```

- WinForm (Drag to app window)

You should add DragDrop event:

private void YourElementControl_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)

```
    {
       ...
       foreach (string path in (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop))
            {
                File.Copy(path, DirPath + Path.GetFileName(path));
            }
       ...
    }
```

[Source with full code](https://www.brainbeast.best/drag-and-drop-on-c-sharp-in-wpf-dot-net/).

Answer (score 0):

Note that for this to work, you also need to set the dragDropEffect within _drawEnter...

```
private void Form1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("DragEnter!");
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
}
```

Source: [Drag and Drop not working in C# Winforms Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26628492/drag-and-drop-not-working-in-c-sharp-winforms-application)