# Set form backcolor to custom color

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

How can I set a form's backcolor to a custom color (such as light pink) using C# code?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

If you want to set the form's back color to some arbitrary RGB value, you can do this:

```
this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 232, 232); // this should be pink-ish
```

Comment: @MusiGenesis It works fine for me too, but it says: "Virtual member call in constructor", what does it mean, should I do anything about it? :)

Comment: @radbyx This is many moons later, but the answer to your question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119506/virtual-member-call-in-a-constructor.  In summary, sealing your class will make the warning go away.

Comment: "using System.Drawing;"  Preprocessor need to use

Answer (score 15):

With Winforms you can use Form.BackColor to do this.
From within the Form's code:

```
BackColor = Color.LightPink;
```

If you mean a [WPF Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.background(v=VS.100).aspx) you can use the Background property.
From within the Window's code:

```
Background = Brushes.LightPink;
```

Answer (score 0):

Define BackGround Color ShowDialog

```
ColorDialog bgColor = new ColorDialog();
```

After if you want change the color according to selected color

```
bgColor.ShowDialog();
this.BackColor = bgColor.Color;
```