# Changing the BackColor of a Windows Form

Tags: c#, backcolor

Why can't I change the backcolor of my form this way?

```
MainForm.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
```

This is what I get in the console:

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.BackColor.get' (CS0120)
```

Comment: Use `this.BackColor` instead or just `BackColor`

Comment: possible duplicate.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891686/set-form-backcolor-to-custom-color

Comment: thnx, @icemanind :) ur a gr8 help....it worked :)

Comment: simply changed it to this:

this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;

Comment: Try this one hope it will help you. [Solution Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZVCw.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Static Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx) are classes that cannot be instantiated. Static classes have static methods or static properties (or both). When you use a line like this:

```
MainForm.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black; // <class name>.<property>
```

What the C# compiler does first is look for a local class variable called `MainForm`. Since there was none, it then looked outside your local scope and found your `Windows.Form` class called `MainForm`.

It then looked to see if the class `MainForm` has a static property called `BackColor`. The compiler then said "Oh look, there is a property called `BackColor`, but its not static", which is when the compiler complained and threw you the error you experienced.

By changing it to `this.BackColor`, the compiler knew you wanted to set the background color OF THIS INSTANCE of MainForm, which was `this` or, by default, `form1`:

```
this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black; // <this instance>.<property>
```

And as a side note, the keyword `this` is not required. Omitting it assumes "this object". You can do this just as well:

```
BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black; // <this instance>.<property>
```

Hope this makes more sense!

Answer (score 4):

You're using MainForm as if it were a static class. Either make your form static or create an instance of it.

```
MainForm form = new MainForm();
```

Then use

```
form.BackColor = Color.Black;
```

---

Adding to the comment to your question, stick

```
 this.BackColor = Color.Black;
```

inside of a method of your form, and just call that method. Like so.

```
void changeBackColor(Color color)
{
    this.BackColor = color;
}
```

That will let you pass a color to the method and changes the BackColor accordingly.

Hope this helps. I'd recommend reading a book about C#. Objects can't be used before being initialized. It's a pretty elementary concept.