# how to change the backcolor of a richtextbox to a System color

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to programmatically set the color property of a richtextbox to a system Color, rather than a custom color. For example (in the GUI, you could have System colors of type info, menu, window e.t.c)

Comment: Instead of Colors.xxx use SystemColors.xxx: `richTextBox1.BackColor = SystemColors.Desktop;`

Comment: How do i do that exactly?

Comment: Use [SystemColors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemcolors.aspx) members to get the desired colors. And set the appropriate RichTextBox color property to its value.

Comment: Thank you @Taw...Was trying System.Colors

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set form backcolor to custom color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891686/set-form-backcolor-to-custom-color)