# Virtual member call in a constructor when assigning value to property

Tags: c#, properties, resharper, virtual, abstract-class

I have an Abstract class and a Derived class. The abstract class defines an abstract property named Message. In the derived class, the property is implemented by overriding the abstract property. The constructor of the derived class takes a string argument and assigns it to its Message property. In Resharper, this assignment leads to a warning "Virtual member call in constructor".

The AbstractClass has this definition:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {
    public abstract string Message { get; set; }

    protected AbstractClass() {}

    public abstract void PrintMessage();
}
```

And the DerivedClass is as follows:

```
using System;

public class DerivedClass : AbstractClass {
    private string _message;

    public override string Message {
        get { return _message; }
        set { _message = value; }
    }

    public DerivedClass(string message) {
        Message = message; // Warning: Virtual member call in a constructor
    }

    public DerivedClass() : this("Default DerivedClass message") {}

    public override void PrintMessage() {
        Console.WriteLine("DerivedClass PrintMessage(): " + Message);
    }
}
```

I did find some other questions about this warning, but in those situations there is an actual call to a method. For instance, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119506/virtual-member-call-in-a-constructor), the answer by Matt Howels contains some sample code. I'll repeat it here for easy reference.

```
class Parent {
    public Parent() {
        DoSomething();
    }
    protected virtual void DoSomething() {};
}

class Child : Parent {
    private string foo;
    public Child() { foo = "HELLO"; }
    protected override void DoSomething() {
        Console.WriteLine(foo.ToLower());
    }
}
```

Matt doesn't describe on what error the warning would appear, but I'm assuming it will be on the call to DoSomething in the Parent constructor. In this example, I understand what is meant by a virtual member being called. The member call occurs in the base class, in which only a virtual method exists.

In my situation however, I don't see why assigning a value to `Message` would be calling a virtual member. Both the call to and the implementation of the Message property are defined in the derived class.

Although I can get rid of the error by making my Derived Class `sealed`, I would like to understand why this situation is resulting in the warning.

**Update**
Based on Brett's answer, I did my best to create a ChildClass derived from the DerivedClass that will ultimately result in an exception. This is what I came up with:

```
using System;

public class ChildClass : DerivedClass {
    private readonly string _foo;

    public ChildClass() : base("Default ChildClass Message") {
        _foo = "ChildClass foo";
    }

    public override string Message {
        get { return base.Message; }
        set {
            base.Message = value;
            Console.WriteLine(_foo.ToUpper() + " received " + value);
        }
    }
}
```

Off course it's a bit silly to be using `_foo` in the Message setter, but the point is that ReSharper doesn't see anything wrong with this class.

If however, you try to use the ChildClass in a program like this:

```
internal class Program {
    private static void Main() {
        var childClass = new ChildClass();
        childClass.PrintMessage();
    }
}
```

You'll get a NullReferenceException when creating the ChildClass object. The exception will be thrown by the ChildClass' attempt to use `_foo.ToUpper()` as `_foo` isn't initialized yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because your Message property can be overridden by `class ChildClass : DerivedClass` - at which point it's possible to invoke code in Message on `ChildClass` from the ctor in `DerivedClass`, and your `ChildClass` instance may not be full initialised.

That's why making your `DerivedClass` sealed solves the problem - it cannot be inherited.

Comment: That's weird. Why can a ChildClass override my Message property when it's not virtual in DerivedClass? Is an override implicitly virtual?

Comment: You override the implementation, you don't change the fact that it's a virtual member.  So, yes.

Comment: You could also mark the *method* as `sealed` when you override it, which means nobody can override it in descendant classes -- so it's effectively no longer virtual. That should remove the error as well.

Comment: @Joe: Good point. I was wondering if there was a way to just make that one method not be virtual anymore.

Comment: Today I noticed I even get the warning if I create a Form and set its `Text` property in the constructor. Isn't this something that is very normal to do? If the Form is supposed to have a title I would set the Text property in the constructor (or in a method being called from the constructor).