# Overridden Refresh() not called for child UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, refresh

I run into a strange problem (WinXP / .NET 2.0). I use a WinForm UserControl that overrides Refresh():

```
public override void Refresh()
    {
        DoSomeStuff();
        base.Refresh();
    }
```

I add this UserControl as child to another control and want to refresh all child controls:

```
ParentControl : UserControl
{
  [...]

  public ParentControl (...)
  {
    [...]

    UserControl ChildControl = ModelEngine.MainControl; // UserControl as mentioned above
    this.Controls.Add(ChildControl);

    [...]

    ModelEngine.MainControl.Refresh(); //#1
    this.Refresh(); // #2
  }
}
```

Calling the Refresh() method directly (#1) works fine.
I expected that I can call Refresh() on the parent class (#2) and this would trigger a recursive Refresh() on all child controls (as explained in MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh.aspx). However, the overridden Refresh() in the child control is not executed. 
BTW: setting ControlStyles.UserPaint to true didn't change the behaviour.

Of course I could call Refresh() directly (as in #1) or write my own recursive Refresh(). But I am wondering whether this bug is an indication of a bigger problem somewhere in my code...

So is there an obvious error in my code or is this the regular behaviour of .NET?

Answer (score 1):

As it says in the page to which you linked:

> Notes to Inheritors
>
> When overriding Refresh in a derived
>   class, be sure to call the base
>   class's Refresh method so the control
>   and its child controls are invalidated
>   and redrawn.

You must call the base `Refresh()` method explicitly. Otherwise, there would be no way to *not* run the base method, and the whole concept of overrides would be lost.

Comment: In his ParentControl class, he doesn't seem to override the base Refresh() method, so it looks like he *is* calling the base method when using "this".

Comment: @Ocelot20 That is true, but he is calling a virtual method in the constructor. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119506/virtual-member-call-in-a-constructor

Comment: My apologies, didn't realize it was a virtual method.