# In C#, is it safe to call virtual method from constructor?

Tags: c#, constructor, polymorphism, virtual

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Virtual member call in a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119506/virtual-member-call-in-a-constructor)

In C#, is it safe to call virtual method from constructor? What does the language specification say? Please quote from the spec as well. By *safe*, I mean would it call the implementation of the derived class?

This doubt exists in my mind, because in C++, it is *not* safe to call virtual function from constructor.

Comment: Alright! A duplicate exists. Voted for close then!

Comment: Why do you define "safe" as calling the implementation of the derived class? One could make the reasonable argument that C++'s technique (of calling the method implementation based on what parts of the class have been initialized) is the safer choice.

Comment: @Eric: One could make that argument if I leave that that vague!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it, but you shouldn't. I think C# even gives you a warning for it.

It becomes very dangerous when the function has been overridden by a derived class, because you're now calling into that function before the derived class's constructor has been called.

Comment: In C++, the derived class implementation is NOT called, for exactly that reason.

Comment: In C++ memory might not be fully initialized, but that's not an issue in C#.

Comment: @Gabe: Memory initialized is not the same as the invariants being established.

Comment: @Ben: That's very true. However, since the memory is guaranteed to be initialized, you can reliably detect that your invariants may not hold and act properly. I'm not saying it's a good idea, but you can write reliable code that does it.

Comment: @Gabe: anyway, in C++, the derived class memory isn't fully initialized, which is why the derived version of the function isn't called.  The version which is called matches a base subobject whose memory is fully initialized (all subobjects of the active dynamic type have been constructed).

Answer (score 1):

It's not safe, since the virtual function would be called before the matching constructor has had a chance to establish the class invariants.

In contrast, it IS safe in C++ -- the function which is called is called during the matching constructor, not before.

Comment: I edited my question, saying what I meant by "safe".