# use a derived class's field in the base class in c#

Tags: c#, inheritance, field, derived

I want to have a field, defined in a base class, that will affect the creation of an object belonging to the base class. However, I want to be able to override the value of the field, **before** the Base class cto'r is called. An example:

```
class ObjNeedParam
{
    public ObjNeedParam(int p)
    {
        val = p;
    }
    int val;
    int Value{get{return Value;}}
}
class Base
{
    public Base()
    {
        obj = new ObjNeedParam(paramVal);
    }
    ObjNeedParam obj;
    protected int paramVal = 1;
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public Derived()
    { 
        //Once I'm here, obj has already been created with paramVal=1 instead of 2!            
        dummy = 3;
    }
    new int paramVal = 2;
    int dummy;
}
```

Comment: make paramval a virtual property and override it

Comment: you will have to pass the value to the base constructor

Comment: I understand the question and the answer - what I don't understand are the 2 downvotes... Why would you downvote without a comment in such a case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This practice is somewhat questionable, so you might want to rethink your approach here.

If you still want to go ahead with this, the correct way is to have a `virtual` method that provides this value to the base constructor:

```
class Base
{
    public Base()
    {
        obj = new ObjNeedParam(GetParamVal());
    }

    protected virtual int GetParamVal() { return 1; }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    protected override int GetParamVal() { return 2; }
}
```

**You will have to ensure that the `override` does not use any class members of `Derived` that get initialized in `Derived`'s constructor** because that constructor will not have run yet at the point where the override is called! See [Virtual member call in a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119506/virtual-member-call-in-a-constructor).

**Update:** It is somewhat questionable because when constructing an object of some derived type the compiler has a problem to solve: in what order should the fields be initialized and the constructors run so that any method call from inside any constructor is guaranteed to find the object in a "usable" state?

This problem cannot be solved in the general case because by definition the object is not in a usable state until all constructors have returned, and we are talking about calling methods from *inside* these constructors. So the compiler has to guarantee as much as it can and either prevent or allow you to do things that are not provably safe.

In this scenario C++ (amusingly) prevents the doing of things that are not provably safe, while C# allows it. Therefore it's somewhat questionable because if you don't pay attention it is possible to introduce bugs. A safer approach would be to write the class such that this member is initialized after the constructors have run.

Comment: great, this works! But can you please elaborate on the "somewhat questionable" please? If it's not the right way to go, I would love to know why. Thx!

Comment: @zorbar: Updated the answer, take a look.

Comment: I get it. Thx a lot for the detailed explanantion.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is *not* initialise the field in that way.  One alternative is to make the field a property, and allow overriding by the child class.  Alternatively, allow the field to be set in the base class constructor via a parameter, so you can write code like this:

```
class Base
{
    public Base() : this(1)
    {
    }

    public Base(int param)
    {
        paramVal = param;
    }

    private int paramVal;
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public Derived() : base(2)
    {   
    }
}
```

Ultimately, a field is typically *private* to a class, and is never overrideable by a derived class.  If you want to expose it for a derived class to manipulate then you probably want something other than a field.