# C# inheritance and virtual functions confusion

Tags: c#, inheritance, virtual

Today I came up with an interesting problem. I noticed that the following code:

```
class A
{
    public A()
    {
        Print();
    }
    public virtual void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Print in A");
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public B()
    {
        Print();
    }

    public override void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Print in B");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new B();
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Print in B
Print in B
```

I want to know why does it print the "Print in B" twice.

Comment: You don't get a @JonSkeet answer every day! Take a lesson from the Yoda of Stack Overflow my friend.

Comment: You get a compiler warning about this telling that the class should be sealed?

Comment: @JohanLarsson Not really. No warning, compiled fluently. VS 2010, 4.0 Framework

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I want to know why does it print the "Print in B" twice.

You're calling a virtual method twice, on the same object. The object is an instance of `B` even during `A`'s constructor, and so the overridden method will be called. (I believe that in C++, the object only "becomes" an instance of the subclass *after* the base class constructor has executed, as far as polymorphism is concerned.)

Note that this means that overridden methods called from a constructor will be executed *before the derived class's constructor body has had a chance to execute*. This is dangerous. You should almost never call abstract or virtual methods from a constructor, for precisely this reason.

EDIT: Note that when you don't provide another constructor call to "chain" to using either `: this(...)` or `: base(...)` in the constructor declaration, it's equivalent to using `: base()`. So `B`'s constructor is equivalent to:

```
public B() : base()
{
    Print();
}
```

For more on constructor chaining, see [my article on the topic](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/constructors.html).

Comment: Isn't it an implicit call 
I gues the MSIL is equal for 
public B() 
and
public B() : base()?

Comment: I think what's important to note here is that the default constructor on `A` is called when creating a new instance of `B`, even without explicitly calling it as in `public B() : base()`

Comment: @sybkar: I'd assumed that was a given, but I'll make it explicit.

Comment: Everyone should have a Jon Skeet in every home :-D

Comment: @NM: Yes. Do not call `Print()` in `B`.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike C++ where calls of virtuals in the constructor are restricted to the definition within the class itself, the overrides are fully honored in C#'s constructors. The practice is frowned upon, and for a good reason ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/119506/335858)), but it is still allowed: `A`'s constructor calls the override supplied by `B`, producing the output that you see. This is the normal behavior of overriden virtual functions.

Answer (score 2):

Because B override's the `Print` method. Your variable `a` is of type `B`, and B's `Print` method looks like this:

```
public override void Print()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Print in B");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not call a base class constructor, the default constructor for the base class will be called implicitly ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx)).

You would not get the double output if you defined your class A constructors this way:

```
class A
{
    public A()
    {
        // does nothing
    }

    public A(object a)
    {
        Print();
    }
}
```

The reason it prints "Print in B" both times is that Print() is overridden in the class B so B.Print() is what is called by both constructors.

I think you can force the A.Print() to be called in the A constructor as follows:

```
class A
{
    public A()
    {
        ((A)this).Print();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why do you think saying `(A)this` will help? It's still a `B`, not an `A`.

Comment: @Jeppe - Did not verify. May only work if B declares [new void Print()], though can't do this is Print() is virtual.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have an instance of B which overrides Print, so that overridden method gets called.  Also, A's ctor will run, followed by B's which is why it gets printed twice.