# Linq - drill down with find

Tags: linq, join, lambda

I am completely new to linq and need help.
These are my poco classes:

```
public class User {
   public User()
   {
      this.Profiles = new List<Profile>();
   }

   public Guid ID { get; set; }        
   public bool IsValid{ get; set; }       
   public virtual ICollection<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }
}

public class Profile {
   public Profile() {
      this.Users = new List<User>();
      this.Customers = new List<Customer>();
   }

   public Guid ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; } 
   public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}

public class Customer {
   public Customer()
   {
      this.Profiles = new List<Profile>();
   }

 public Guid ID { get; set; }
 public string Number { get; set; }       
 public virtual ICollection<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to search for valid Users with special customers. Special customers would come from another user. So I would send another user as method argument.

Is it even possible with linq or I need stored procedure to solv the problem?

Best regards

Comment: Please try to better describe your problem. Could you post e.g. some pseudo code of method you are trying write (with possible input and exptected output)?

Comment: @mipe34 Hi,  List<User> user = FindAllUsersBySameCustomers(User sourceuser); I want a list of users that have same customers like that provided in the method. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
public static List<User> FindAllUsersBySameCustomers(User sourceuser)
{
    var res = sourceuser.Profiles.SelectMany(p => p.Customers)
                                 .SelectMany(c => c.Profiles)
                                 .SelectMany(p => p.Users)
                                 .Distinct();
    return res.ToList();
}
```

But beware, it will work only if your relations are populated (included) like in my example [here](http://ideone.com/03qPox).

*NOTE*

*You should not call virtual member inside the constructor.* Anwer is here on SO: [Virtual member call in a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119506/virtual-member-call-in-a-constructor)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
/// <summary>
    /// Search for valid Users with special customers. 
    /// Special customers would come from another user. 
    /// So I would send another user as method argument.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<User> FindValidUsersWithSpecialCustomers(List<User> allUsers, User anotherUser)
    {   
        var specialCustomers = anotherUser.Profiles.SelectMany(aProfile => aProfile.Customers);//.Select(cust => cust.Number == "SpecialCustomerNumber" && cust.ID == new Guid("SpecialCustomerGuid"));

        Func<IEnumerable<Customer>, IEnumerable<Customer>, Boolean> IsSpecialCustomersPresentInThisCustomersList =
            delegate(IEnumerable<Customer> customerList, IEnumerable<Customer> specialCustomersList)
            {
                if ((from cust in customerList where specialCustomersList.Contains(cust) select cust).Any())
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            };

        var validUsersWithSpecialCustomers = (from user in allUsers where user.IsValid && IsSpecialCustomersPresentInThisCustomersList(user.Profiles.SelectMany(p => p.Customers), specialCustomers) select user);

        return validUsersWithSpecialCustomers.ToList();
    }
```