# C# Call base class' constructor after own constructor?

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, constructor, superclass

How can I call base class' constructor **after** I've called my own constructor?

The problem is, base class' constructor calls an abstract method (overridden in sub class), which needs to access variable `x`, initialized in sub class' constructor?

Short example code:

```
abstract class BaseClass
{
    protected string my_string;

    protected abstract void DoStuff();

    public BaseClass()
    {
        this.DoStuff();
    }
}

class SubClass : BaseClass
{
    private TextBox tb;

    public SubClass()
        : base()
    {
        this.my_string = "Short sentence.";
    }

    protected override void DoStuff()
    {
        // This gets called from base class' constructor
        // before sub class' constructor inits my_string
        tb.Text = this.my_string;
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Based on answers, it obviously is not possible. Is there an automated way to call `this.DoStuff();` on every object of `SubClass` once they're created? Of course I could just add `this.DoStuff();` after all the other lines in sub class' constructor, but having around 100 of these classes, it feels stupid. Any other solution, or should I use the manual one?

Comment: Actually I don't think you can, at least not in a standart way (using reflection perhaps you could but I don't think it's a good approach)

Comment: You can't. Think about it - your class is reliant on it's parent class. How can you create an instance of your class without creating the parent first?

Comment: See my edit. I guess I'll just manually add one line in every sub class' constructor, not that big of a deal. Still worth asking :-)

Answer (score 30):

You can't.

Also, you generally shouldn't call `virtual` methods in a constructor. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/119543/870604).

---

Depending on your actual code and not the simple example you wrote, you could pass values as parameters of the base constructor and the `DoStuff` method. For example:

```
abstract class BaseClass
{
    private string my_string;

    protected abstract void DoStuff(string myString);

    public BaseClass(string myString)
    {
        this.my_string = myString;
        this.DoStuff(this.my_string);
    }
}

class SubClass : BaseClass
{
    private TextBox tb;

    public SubClass()
        : base("Short sentence.")
    {
    }

    protected override void DoStuff(string myString)
    {
        tb.Text = myString;
    }
}
```

If it's not possible with your actual code, then writing multiple `DoStuff()` will do the job. Also remember to seal your `SubClass` class so nobody else will be able to introduce bugs by modifying the `DoStuff` method another time.

Answer (score 5):

I would not call an abstract method in the constructor as it can happen that the constructor for the instance that invokes the method has not executed

*When a virtual method is called, the actual type that executes the method is not selected until run time. When a constructor calls a virtual method, it is possible that the constructor for the instance that invokes the method has not executed.
To fix a violation of this rule, do not call a type's virtual methods from within the type's constructors.*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182331%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it like that. But you can put your initiation code of the master class into a separate initialize method. You then can call that method in your specific constructor >after the constructor code.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't construct a class before its constructor actually runs?  It requires a greater level of responsibility on how the derived class is created and probably not a best practice, but it appears to work.

```
abstract class BaseClass {
    protected string my_string;

    protected abstract void DoStuff();

    public BaseClass() {
        this.DoStuff();
    }
}

class SubClass: BaseClass {
    TextBox tb;

    bool Constructed = false;
    void Constructor() {
        if (!Constructed) {
            Constructed = true;
            this.my_string = "Short sentence.";
        }
    }
    public SubClass()
        : base() {
        Constructor();
    }

    protected override void DoStuff() {
        Constructor();
        // This gets called from base class' constructor
        // before sub class' constructor inits my_string
        tb.Text = this.my_string;
    }
}
```