# Why override method of SecondChild class is not getting invoked twice?

Tags: c#, constructor, virtual-functions

I am not clear about why the `SecondChild` class `DoSomething` is not getting called again when `Child` class is getting initialized.

```cs
class Parent
{
    public Parent()
    {
       DoSomething();
    }
    protected virtual  void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Parent Method");
    }
}
```

```cs
class Child : Parent
{
    private string foo;

    public Child()
    {
        foo = "HELLO";
    }
    protected override void DoSomething()
    {
       Console.WriteLine(foo.ToLower());
    }
}
```

```cs
class SecondChild : Parent
{
    public SecondChild()
    {
        var c = new Child();
    }

    protected override void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In second Child");
    }
}
```

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SecondChild c = new SecondChild();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I was expecting that `DoSomething()` of `SecondChild` will be called twice here, but instead `Child` class `DoSomething()` is invoked which will give **NullException**.

Comment: Please use a debugger: You create only _one_ `SecondChild` instance. In that constructor, you create a _`Child`_ instance (not a `SecondChild`), so why should `SecondChild.DoSomething()` should be called twice?

Comment: You should include actual and expected output to the question. Also, read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119506/virtual-member-call-in-a-constructor, it might explain some things

Comment: Add expected and actual outputs. "called again" is too fuzzy.

Comment: Don't call virtual methods in your constructor.

Comment: Btw: [see this question for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17991419/solving-the-virtual-method-call-in-constructor-issue)

Comment: Quick question: `DoSomething` is called in the `Parent` base class's constructor (before `Child`s constructor), executing code from `Child`, that accesses an uninitialized variable `foo`. Does that code even execute? isn't `foo` still `null`? `ToLower` should fail, shouldn't it?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer, that is absolutelly correct.

Comment: "which will give __NullException__" is exactly _why_ you shouldn't call virtual members from a constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have adjusted Your definition a bit:

```
class Parent
{
    protected string foo;
    public Parent()
    {
        foo = "Parent1";
        DoSomething();
        foo = "Parent2";
    }
    protected virtual void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Parent Method");
    }
}

class Child : Parent
{

    public Child()
    {
        foo = "HELLO";
    }
    protected override void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(foo.ToLower());
    }
}

class SecondChild : Parent
{
    public SecondChild()
    {
        var c = new Child();
    }

    protected override void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In second Child");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SecondChild c = new SecondChild();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Output for this will be:

> In second Child
>
> parent1

Reason why? Look at the method call order:

```
new SecondChild()
  -> SecondChild:base()
      -> base.DoSomething() //virtual
    -> SecondChild.DoSomething()
  -> new Child()
    -> Child:base()
      -> base.DoSomething() //virtual
    -> Child.DoSomething()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well DoSomething() its get called when create an instance of SecondChild class, but when you create and instance  of class Child, first it execute the constructor of Parent class, which is calling  DoSomething method of the child class which is OK, but because the constructor of Child class is not executed yet, foo field is not yet and doing foo.ToLower() throws null reference  exception.

DoSomething is getting called twice once of Child class and once for SecondChild, but for Child class is throwing exception because of foo is null

So the tricky part here the base constructor get executed before the constructor of the derived class