# Java - Subclass calls supers constructor which calls subclass method instead of its own

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, constructor, overriding

I'll start with a code example:

```
class A {
    public A() {
        f(); //When accessed through super() call this does not call A.f() as I had expected.
    }

    public void f() {} //I expect this to be called from the constructor.
}

class B extends A {
    private Object o;

    public B() {
        super();
        o = new Object(); //Note, created after super() call.
    }

    @Override
    public void f() {
        //Anything that access o.
        o.hashCode(); //Throws NullPointerException.
        super.f();
    }
}

public class Init {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
    }
}
```

This program throws a `NullPointerException`. When the object b enters the constructor of its superclass `A` and makes a call to the method `f()` which is overridden by the class B `B.f()` is called, instead of `A.f()` which I would have expected.

I thought a superclass wasn't supposed to know if it was subclassed or not but surely this can be used by a class to tell if it's been subclassed or not? What's the reason behind this? Is there any workaround if I really want `A.f()` to be called instead of `B.f()`?

Thanks in advance.

---

**Follow up question:**

Thanks for the answers. I now understand why it is like it is, but here's a follow up question. Perhaps I'm mistaken but a principle of subtyping is that the supertype should not know that it's been subtyped. This "mechanism" lets a class know if it's been subclassed or not. Consider this code example:

```
class A {
    private boolean isSubclassed = true;

    public A() {
        f(); //A.f() unsets the isSubclassed flag, B.f() does not.
        if(this.isSubclassed) {
            System.out.println("I'm subclassed.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("I'm not subclassed.");
        }
    }

    public void f() {
        this.isSubclassed = false;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public B() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void f() {}
}

public class Init {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new B(); //Subclass.
        new A();
    }
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
I'm subclassed.
I'm not subclassed.
```

Here `A` knows it's been subclassed. It's unkown by whom but that doesn't matter. How is this explained? Am I misinformed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `NullPointerException` occurs because when you construct an instance of B, the parent constructor (in A) is invoked. This constructor calls the `f()` method but since the actual type of the object is B, the overridden `f()` method in B is invoked.

```
@Override
public void f() {
    //Anything that access o.
    o.hashCode(); //Throws NullPointerException as o has not been initialised yet
    super.f();
}
```

**The lesson here is never to call a method in a constructor which can be overridden by a subclass.**

Comment: Yeah, guess he visioned it in a C++ way rather than Java way.

Answer (score 1):

This is why you shouldn't call non-private methods from constructors. There is no workaround, except making the method private.

Comment: ...and remove the `@Override` annotation, as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is the reason that override hide the own method. At the call of `f()` at `super` class constructor, it hide `super` class method call. Actually it is call to `subclass` overided method.

```
 class A{
 public A() {
    f(); // It call the subclass overided method.
  }
 // This method is hide due to override.
  public void f() {
    } 
 }

class B extends A {
// This method is called before constructor where Object o is Null, hence you
// got NullPointerExcetion.
@Override
public void f() {
    // Anything that access o.
    o.hashCode(); // Throws NullPointerException.
    super.f();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class A {
    public A() {
             System.out.println(1);
         f(); 
             // where super(),this will be called by subclass ,but subclass's o is null 
    }
    public void f() {
        System.out.println(4);
    }
}
```