# Any difference in behaviour using this.X and base.X when refering to inherited properties/variables?

Tags: c#

If I have a very simple class like so:

```
public class Example
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public Example(int numberArg)
    {
        this.Number = numberArg;
    }
}
```

And I have a derivative class like so:

```
public class AnotherExample : Example
{
    public int DoubleNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Number * 2;
        }
    }
    public AnotherExample(int numberArg) : base(numberArg) {}
}
```

What difference is there, if any, if I use `this.Number` to refer to the `AnotherExample` objects base `Number` property than if I use `base.Number` to refer to it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Number` is not overridden there is no difference, as `this.Number` will resolve correctly in the chain of inheritance.

<sub>This also means that calling `this.Member` in a base class, if overridden in a derived class will again use the inheritance chain and find the derived implementation.</sub>


If it has been overridden, using `base` will *always* go to the base class's version of that property, whereas `this.Number` will first go to your overridden version.

If you plan on calling `virtual` members inside your constructors, please be aware of the general advice around it:

[Virtual member call in a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119506/virtual-member-call-in-a-constructor)

<sub>This answer is leaving out the explanation about member hiding as the OP example is simpler than that.</sub>

Comment: Ahh I see, so say I do some work with the `Number` property in my derivative class's ctor but use `base.Number` to access it via a `get` property, the work will not be reflected?

Comment: @Kenneth has an example of what I was talking about, thanks for the information!

Comment: @nabir Oh, calling a base class constructor? Yes, I see. Mind that in his example, `this.Number` within `Example` will call into `AnotherExample.Number` and won't do anything as `set` is an empty implementation.

Comment: Thanks again @Adam Houldsworth, that was at the back of my mind for a while :P

Answer (score 2):

In this case, there is no difference. In case you override it will take the value from the base class instead of the inherited class:

```
public class Example {
    public virtual int Number { get; set; }
    public Example(int numberArg) {
        this.Number = numberArg;
    }
}

public class AnotherExample : Example {
    public override int Number 
    {
        get{return 5;}
        set{}
    }
    public int DoubleNumber {
        get {
            return this.Number * 2; // returns 10
            return base.Number * 2 // returns 2 times whatever the value is 
        }
    }
    public AnotherExample(int numberArg) : base(numberArg) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a variable in derived class that has the same name with in the base class.In this case you need to use `this` and `base` keywords to avoid ambiguity.For example:

```
public class Base
{
    public int Number = 0;
}

public class Derived : Base
{
   public int Number;

   public Derived() 
   {
       this.Number = base.Number + 5;
   }
}
```