# Why can I pass a func of a virtual function in a constructor?

Tags: c#, resharper

I do not get a potential virtual function call in constructor warning when I do:

```
   public abstract class B : A
    {
        protected B(IEngine engine) : base(engine)
        {
            C = new C(CanExecuteChange);
        }

        public C C{ get; }
        public abstract bool CanExecuteChange();
    }
```

Where class C's constructor takes a `Func<bool>`

But CanExecuteChange might be virtual? So couldn't we be calling a virtual function in the constructor?

Comment: `But CanExecuteChange might be virtual` how do you foresee that?

Comment: I think it's just a case of Resharper not going out of it's way to find this potential issue since the method is not actually called directly inside of the constructor.

Comment: @Jonesopolis Well, it's `abstract`.  All `abstract` methods are, by definition, implicitly `virtual`.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that C# is language you are using? Because unlike C++ there is no* problems calling virtual functions from constructor in C# (* - ok it will likely behave badly too but in well-defined way unlike C++ - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119506/virtual-member-call-in-a-constructor)

Comment: Are you expecting a compiler warning or something like a resharper warning? Perhaps you should explain why you think it *should* be giving you a warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because you're *passing* `CanExecuteChange` to another method, doesn't mean it's actually being *called*. If your code looks like this:

```
public class C
{
    private Func<bool> _func;

    public C(Func<bool> func)
    {
        _func = func;
    }
}
```

then the ctor of `C` is just *storing* the passed-in `Func` for later and there's nothing to worry about.

Even if the `C` ctor *does* invoke the passed `Func`:

```
public class C
{
    public C(Func<bool> func)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(func());
    }
}
```

R# necessarily has a **finite limit** on how deep it will look and will not flag this.