# Construct derived-class properties without virtual member call in constructor

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, design-patterns

I have some nested classes, `BaseOuter` and `BaseInner`, and child classes `DerivedOuter` and `DerivedInner`.  `BaseOuter` has property `BaseInner baseInner;`, and when I instantiate `DerivedOuter` I want the runtime type of `baseInner` property to be `DerivedInner`.

I first solved this like I have below, using a virtual initializer to instantiate `baseInner`, that is overriden in `DerivedOuter`.  That allows me to do `baseInner = new BaseInner();` vs `baseInner = new DerivedInner();` in the respective initializers.

After noticing a [Resharper warning](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2018.2/VirtualMemberCallInConstructor.html) and doing a [little more reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119506/virtual-member-call-in-a-constructor) I decided I should change it... but how?

A couple of things come to mind.  I could call the initializer after calling the constructor, requiring calling code to do `var baseOuter = new BaseOuter(); baseOuter.Initialize();`.  I can probably use a factory, but I'd have to think about that a little.  Lastly, perhaps there is a design flaw in the class-nesting I want to do?

It's worth pointing out that doing `new BaseInner();` is expensive, and I don't simply want to create it and throw it away.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("new BaseOuter");
        var baseOuter = new BaseOuter();
        Console.WriteLine("\nnew DerivedOuter");
        var derivedOuter = new DerivedOuter();
    }

    class BaseOuter{
        protected BaseInner baseInner;
        public BaseOuter(){
            Console.WriteLine("BaseOuter Constructor");
            /*  lots of stuff I want in derived class */

            // This is an anti-pattern I want to avoid
            //https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2018.2/VirtualMemberCallInConstructor.html
            InitializeInner();
        }

        protected virtual void InitializeInner(){
            Console.WriteLine("    BaseOuter Initialize BaseInner");
            baseInner = new BaseInner();
        }

        protected class BaseInner{
            public int x;
            public BaseInner(){
                /* stuff that is needed in DerivedInner too */
                Console.WriteLine("        BaseInner Constructor");
                x = 2;
            }
        }       
    }

    class DerivedOuter : BaseOuter {
        public DerivedOuter() {
            Console.WriteLine("DerivedOuter Constructor (finished)");
        }

        protected override void InitializeInner(){
            Console.WriteLine("    DerivedOuter Initialize DerivedInner");
            baseInner = new DerivedInner();
        }

        protected class DerivedInner : BaseInner {
            public double y;
            public DerivedInner(){
            Console.WriteLine("        DerivedInner Constructor");
                y = 2d;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
new BaseOuter
BaseOuter Constructor
    BaseOuter Initialize BaseInner
        BaseInner Constructor

new DerivedOuter
BaseOuter Constructor
    DerivedOuter Initialize DerivedInner
        BaseInner Constructor
        DerivedInner Constructor
DerivedOuter Constructor (finished)
```

All of the code can be found here in this [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Yv2e7Q).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach.

It's doing the same thing. The difference is in how the derived class "overrides" the implementation of `BaseInner`. It does so by supplying an implementation to the constructor.

```
internal class BaseOuter
{
    protected BaseInner baseInner;

    protected internal BaseOuter(BaseInner inner = null)
    {
        baseInner = inner ?? new BaseInner();
        Console.WriteLine("BaseOuter Constructor");
        /*  lots of stuff I want in derived class */

        // This is an anti-pattern I want to avoid
        //https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2018.2/VirtualMemberCallInConstructor.html

    }

    protected internal class BaseInner
    {
        public int x;

        public BaseInner()
        {
            /* stuff that is needed in DerivedInner too */
            Console.WriteLine("        BaseInner Constructor");
            x = 2;
        }
    }
}

internal class DerivedOuter : BaseOuter
{
    protected internal DerivedOuter()
     :base(new DerivedInner())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DerivedOuter Constructor (finished)");
    }

    protected internal class DerivedInner : BaseInner
    {
        public double y;

        public DerivedInner()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("        DerivedInner Constructor");
            y = 2d;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to do all-out dependency injection you could remove the default from

```
protected internal BaseOuter(BaseInner inner = null)
```

Which means that `BaseOuter` would be completely decoupled from any implementation of `BaseInner`.

A few other suggestions:

- I wouldn't nest classes inside each other unless there's a really strong need. It's not used a lot so at first glance it's likely to confuse someone.
- If `baseInner` is supposed to be set only when the constructor is called, mark it `readonly`. (ReSharper will probably suggest that.)

Comment: Thanks! `BaseOuter` constructor would have the line `baseInner = inner;` too, correct?

Comment: Yes, I missed a line. The base class would use the implementation provided by the derived class if there is one. But if there isn't one (it's null) then it will specify its own.

Comment: Worth mentioning that if we need to create many inner instances we can pass in a delegate function to do that, such as `(arg) => new DerivedInner(arg)`.