# Call InitializeComponent() from a non xaml.cs super class

Tags: c#, wpf

```
// BaseObjectWindow.cs
public partial class BaseObjectWindow : Window {

    public BaseObjectWindow() {
        // I want to call InitializeComponent() here
    }

    //more constructors

}

// AccountWindow.xaml.cs
public partial class AccountWindow : BaseObjectWindow {

    // I want to remove this whole constructor
    public AccountWindow() : base() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

I want to be able to call `InitializeComponent()` from the base class so I don't have to call it in the subclasses. The reason I want to do this is because `BaseObjectWindow` has multiple constructors and C# refuses to implicitly inherit all constructors if you define at least one.

I'm thinking I can save a lot of time by bypassing declaring all constructor for each and every subclass window I need to make (at least 20) but I can't do that if I can't call `InitializeComponent()` from the super class otherwise the subclass windows initialize as an empty window.

Is there any way to work around this cleanly?

Comment: `SuperClass`, `SubClass` are not proper nomenclature of C#. `initComponents` is not a constructor. What prevents you from calling `InitializeComponent` from the base class?

Comment: Sorry, I made a dirty work around and forgot to clean it up before posting. I decided against it last minute hence asking here. Just edited the code to how it should be.

Comment: The InitializeComponent method is auto-generated from the XAML of the AccountWindow class. You can't call it in a base class.

Comment: I see. I had a feeling as much but thought I'd ask anyway. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is declaring a virtual/abstract method in your base class, which you call in your constructors. Override it in your derivered class and call `InitializeComponent` there.
**Note:** Calling a virtual method in a constructor can lead to some problems. See also [Virtual member call in a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119506/virtual-member-call-in-a-constructor)

As far as I can tell in this case there shouldn't be any problems, please someone correct me if I am wrong.

```
public abstract class BaseWindow : Window
{
    protected BaseWindow()
    {
        OnInitialize();
    }

    public abstract void OnInitialize();
}
```

```
public partial class DerivedWindow : BaseWindow
{
    public override void OnInitialize()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this require each derived class to call `InitializeComponent()`? He wanted to call it from the base class "so I don't have to call it in the subclasses".

Comment: @redcurry: Yes it does. Inherintly there is no way of achieving the desired result in WPF since `InitializeComponent` is "autogenerated" for each class. This might be the best option but I'd rather use abstract class and abstract method instead of virtual.

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen You are right abstract might be the better approach, changed that

Comment: Hi Nosale! Thanks again for answering me. The whole point was so I wouldn't have to call it in each `DerivedWindow'. This seems like a clean compromise at least though!