# C#: How can I set a maximal Value of a property from a derived class? (And not in base class)

Tags: c#, oop, properties, max, overriding

> CannibalGhost : Ghost (CannibalGhost dervies from Ghost)

`CannibalGhost` can eat any sort of Ghosts and get their Height added to his Height. However `Ghosts` should be able to be as big as they want, while `CannibalGhosts` should only be at a maximum Height of 50. It can't surpass under any circumstances. Not via. `set-accessor` and not via constructor.

I have tried so far:

- override `Constructor`:

  > Can't override constructor
- implementing a if(`height >= 50`) in `Set-Accessor`

  does not work if I create an object with a constructor in the `Main-Program`
- implementing a barrier in Main-Code so height never gets over 50

  does not  work if I want new objects of `CannibalGhost` later (and is a mess)
- writing it so `CannibalGhost` does not derive from `Ghost`

  So I am able to write a new constructor and `set-Accessor` with a ceiling of 50.
  It worked but I want `CannibalGhosts` also to be a Ghost (derive from Ghost)

**Summary:**
How can I set the property `Height` of `CannibalGhost` to max 50, but not in the base class `Ghost`?

Comment: Maybe you create the *Ghosts in a Factory, which does the Height check:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

I do not like an approach where the constructor throws an exception if height > 50

Comment: Please show some code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could build `Ghost` in such a way that it knows that some validation is required in derived class(es) without implementing the logic itself in the base class

```
public class Ghost
{
    private int height;

    protected virtual bool IsValidHeight(int newHeight)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public int Height
    {
       get{ return height; }
       set
       {
           if(!IsValidHeight(value) throw new InvalidHeightException(value);
           height = value;
       }
    }
}

public class CannibalGhost 
{
    protected override bool IsValidHeight(int newHeight
    {
        return newHeight <= 50;
    }
}
```

perhaps instead of throwing an exception you want to *limit* the height you could make that virtual method

```
protected virtual int LimitHeight(int newHeight)
{
     return newHeight;
}
```

and

```
protected override int LimitHeight(int newHeight)
{
    return (int)Math.Min(newHeight,50);
}
```

then the setter would just be

```
set
{
    height = LimitHeight(value);  
}
```

This would have no effect on `Ghost` but would limit the derived `CannibalGhost` to 50.

---

In truth, this is not a great solution. You can't know when designing a base class all the places you might want this sort of validation down the line - and its the reason inheritance breaks down for more complex solutions than this simple example.

Does `CannibalGhost` *really* have an `is-a` relationship with `Ghost`? Or is it actually composed of multiple `Ghost` instances (a `has-a-collection-of` relationship). In this case it's height could merely be a sum of all its composed `Ghost` instances with a limit of 50. No inheritance required. Perhaps all ghosts implement `IGhost` for shared behaviours - something to consider!

Comment: I'd be tempted to make `LimitHeight()` protected.

Comment: @MatthewWatson bah all the virtual/override methods here were supposed to be `protected` - thanks good spot. Silly mistake

Answer (score 0):

By making the Height property `virtual` in the base class you can have derived classes implement more specific behaviour by *overriding* it.

Example:

```cs
public class Ghost
{
    public virtual int Height { get; set; }
}

public class CannibalGhost : Ghost
{
    private int _height;
    public override int Height
    {
        get
        {
            return _height;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value > 50)
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"A {nameof(CannibalGhost)} cannot have a height over 50");

            _height = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A problem to watch out for with this approach comes if you want to initialise `Height` in the base class constructor. In that event, you'd be [making a virtual member call from a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119506/virtual-member-call-in-a-constructor) which is bad.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Correct. If anyone finds themselves in this situation then I would move the `_height` field into the base class and make it protected. Then you can set it directly from the constructor without worry.