How do you set derived class fields based on ctor arguments before they are used in virtual methods invoked by base ctors?
Scroll for answer if question isn't reopened / still marked as duplicate
In C#, the compiler places the initialization of self-initialized fields before the call to the base constructor in the derived class constructor.
So given:
class A {
}

class B : A {
    int _foo = 5;
}

we get the following IL for B's ctor:
// _foo = 5;
IL_0000: ldarg.0
IL_0001: ldc.i4.5
IL_0002: stfld int32 B::_foo
// base..ctor();
IL_0007: ldarg.0
IL_0008: call instance void A::.ctor()
// }
IL_000d: nop
IL_000e: ret

One of the reasons I think is that it allows us to do this:
class A {
    public A() {
        Bar();
    }
    
    protected virtual void Bar() {
        Console.WriteLine("Base method");
    }
}

class B : A {
    int _foo = 5;
    public B() {
    }
    protected override void Bar() {
        Console.WriteLine(_foo); // writes 5
    }
}

Then
A b = new B(); // will write 5, not 0.

But if we wanted to use an argument to the constructor of the derived class for setting the field instead of self-initialization of the field we won't be so lucky:
public B(int foo) {
    _foo = foo;
}

Now this still prints 5, and not 42
A b = new B(42); // 5 :(

Are there some hacks/tricks that you use, so that you can set fields of a derived class that virtual methods depend on that might be called from the base class constructor?
EDIT: I don't really believe that this is strictly a duplicate, but I can see the arguments for it.
Anyway, here is an ANSWER to this question that won't work for the related question from 7 years ago, that makes use of a relatively new language feature - Primary constructors that were extended to support classes and structs in C# 12
class C(int foo) : A {
    protected override void Bar() {
        Console.WriteLine(foo);
    }
}

now
A c = new C(42); // prints out 42


I would say: Do not call overridable methods in constructors

Better do b.Bar(); after the constructor initialisation.

the best hack is to apply to code-style and conventions. This is: don't call virtual functions in constructors, at least not if they reference members that aren't fully initialized. Also see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119506/virtual-member-call-in-a-constructor.

What is the task you try to solve using the requested feature? Other solution can exist.

The only rule here is the base class constructor executes in front of the derived constructor. Fields initialize before anything else.

@rotabor question is why would field initialize before call to base constructor if not for virtual methods support?

You can read the specifications, but logically the data structure of the object should be available prior to any method is called. Fields initialize by their type-default values or by values defined in the code. Then any method can be called starting from the most base constructor.

@rotabor yes, the field should be available before method calls. I think they provided half-support for virtual method calls in base constructors with moving the field initialization before base ctor calls. Those fields won't be needed for any other types of calls in base ctor.

@rotabor I've added an answer in the question and addressed your points.
