# Drag and Drop in WPF not working for DataFormats.FileDrop

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop

I am developing WPF application, with severals drag and drop support.

In my application has several controls: listView_A, listView_B, and radioButtons.

my drag and drop works if I drag item from listView_A -> listView_B, listView_A -> radioButtons etc.

But I am unable to drag file from windows to all of these controls (listview and radiobuttons), it just display a "no entry" cursor.

All of the controls has "AllowDrop" set to True.

I had tried all options I had, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a known issue if you are using `Windows Vista` or `Windows 7`. Here is a similar question on StackOverflow:

[C# Drag drop does not work on windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833709/c-drag-drop-does-not-work-on-windows-7)

Comment: Ok, I understand, is because of the privilege thing, if I run in debug mode, it is not working; but if I build it and run from the bin folder, it works. So I assume the deliverable will work too.

Answer (score 0):

The process detailed here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mossbiz/archive/2010/06/10/add-an-assembly-to-the-global-assembly-cache-on-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx seems like it might solve the problem.