# Drag and drop and mouse events

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, mouseevent

My question is why mouse events aren't raised on window when I drag some text using drag and drop from another window?

I have a window where I listen to `MouseEnter` event which is not raised when I try to drag and drop something into it.

How to figure this one out?

Comment: to clarify: events dont get raised when i use my drag and drop implementation also. but I dont mean dnd specific events, that works fine, I mean other mouse events such as MouseEnter, when dragging some stuff onto the window. I cannot find any detailed information why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue:

[Drag and Drop in WPF not working for DataFormats.FileDrop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364556/drag-and-drop-in-wpf-not-working-for-dataformats-filedrop)

[C# Drag drop does not work on windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833709/c-drag-drop-does-not-work-on-windows-7)

Comment: well I have drag and drop working between windows of my own application, but I still need to have mouse events when moving inside the target window. the problem is not so simple.