# WPF richtexbox inlineuicontainer disappears when moving

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, inlineuicontainer

In my WPF application, I have a RichTextBox. I can add a simple control such as TextBlock using this code:

```
TextPointer tp = myRichTextBox.CaretPosition.GetInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
InlineUIContainer myInlineUIContainer = new InlineUIContainer(myTextBlock, tp);
```

My problem comes when I try to move the same control around the RichTextBox. It just simply disappears leaving only a space char.
I have the AllowDrop and IsDocumentEnabled properties set to true.
I've searched all over the web and couldn't find a clear explanation as to why this happens.
Could anyone explain and help me to solve this issue??

Thanks

Comment: I was able to reproduce the same problem.  I even tried adding `Drop`/`PreviewDrop` event handlers to the `InlineUIContainer`/`TextBlock` to see if I could catch them and provide a workaround but to no avail.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Found this as well, seems to be the same problem: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/318192/Csharp-TextBlock-drap-and-drop-operation-in-WPF-Ri

This one seems to be dealing with dragging things into the `RichTextBox`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418493/c-drag-and-drop-in-wpf-richtextbox