# C# WinForms DragEnter never fires

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-7, drag-and-drop

I'm puzzled with this. I attempted implementing drag and drop on a `DataGridView`. Failing to see any events fired, I tried a simple form, with a text box.

I would like to be able to drag files or folders from Windows Explorer.

I'm missing something because these events never fire. I did read about [DragEvents, Windows 7 and UIPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833709/c-sharp-drag-drop-does-not-work-on-windows-7) but I still couldn't get around this.

I'm out of ideas and I welcome your suggestions.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.AllowDrop = true;
    textBox1.AllowDrop = true;
    textBox1.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(textBox1_DragEnter);
    textBox1.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(textBox1_DragDrop);
    textBox1.DragOver += new DragEventHandler(textBox1_DragOver);
}

void textBox1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
}

void textBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
}

void textBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
}
```

It seems that this *should* work. I have a clean install on WP7 64 - with all updates, I don't have virus or malware protection running, or anything (to my knowledge) which could prevent these events firing.

Comment: You're trying to drag from your application to another application ?

Comment: The form's DragEnter event handler won't fire, you didn't subscribe the event.  No obvious reason why the text box' event won't fire.  Set a breakpoint on it and drag a file from Windows Explorer to the box.

Comment: @YochaiTimmer I updated the post, I am trying to drag files from Explorer.

Comment: @HansPassant I wired this up in the designer. I've removed it from the example. None of these events fire - that's my issue.

Comment: Well, you current snippet just doesn't repro the problem nor is there an obvious explanation for the failure.  Try it on another machine.  Btw, very strange to have a constructor named "form1".  The boilerplate one is always Form1, capital eff.  *Always* copy-paste a snippet, don't type it in by hand.

Comment: @HansPassant The boiler plate was Form1 - good catch. I have pasted the code. Just to confirm, when you use this code it fires DragEvent? I will try another machine.

Comment: I"m facing this same issue. but with a dataGridView and tabControl. Everything works fine as long as my drag-n-drop source is from another app. How do I get this to work with another winForm instance created from with my current project?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I had the same issue. it was only because I was debugging from a "run as administrator" session. I think that since VISTA there is a security that prevents from dropping to a privileged application.

Comment: This is the kind of stuff that breaks your head

Comment: You deserve a medal for this solution.

Comment: sorry to put a "thank you!!!!" comment... this problem is an ackward behavior that windows not notifies anything about that, damn 3 hours trying to make a drag&drop work...

Comment: I could not agree more with the statement *This is the kind of stuff that breaks your head*; I spent hours figuring out why the events weren't firing  ... I was debugging from a *Run as Administrator* session. (I am using Windows 10)

Comment: Thank you for saving me three hours of design time!

Answer (score 5):

I found that while I was running my Forms application in debug mode from Visual Studio, it didn't work. Only when I ran it outside of VS does it work perfectly. Presumably this is also something to do with security on Windows 7 (and possibly later versions).