# Drag and drop file in windows 8 with c# (It's likely Windows 8 is preventing from drag and drop file)

Tags: winforms, drag-and-drop

In this project, I :

- use WinForm C#
- enabled `AllowDrop = true`
- disable UAC Control
- turn off Windows Firewall, Windows Defender

But I can't drag file in Windows 8 so I can drag in Windows 7, Vista and XP normally.

How do I enable drag and drop file in Windows 8 ?

Or

How do I change my code to drag and drop file in Windows 8?

Comment: If you run the program as Administrator does that make any difference? Could be similar cause to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833709/c-sharp-drag-drop-does-not-work-on-windows-7)

Comment: Okay - I got it to work on my computer. I'm just not sure how! The first time I ran it as Administrator drag drop still didn't work for me... but now it just works without elevating any permissions.
The only other thing I did was change the permissions to a Program Data folder to prevent an exception. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

"How to fully disable UAC on Windows 8

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > Microsoft > Windows > CurrentVersion > Policies > System
```

Then Find this Key EnableLUA, Double Click on it and change the Value data from 1 to 0."