# How to do DragAcceptFiles in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-shell

I'm looking for the least painful way (that is, with the least code) to implement [DragAcceptFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776406(VS.85).aspx) on the main window of a C# project.

I've been searching on the net, and it looks like I'll have to DllImport DragAcceptFiles, and override WndProc to catch and handle WM_DROPFILES messages.

Doesn't the .net-framework provide this somewhere?
Isn't there a proper way to add message handlers to a form other than overriding WndProc and have it do an extra if on almost all other messages that come through?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I drag and drop files into a c# application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68598/how-do-i-drag-and-drop-files-into-a-c-application)

Comment: Ah, one of my upvoted questions that never got accepted as the answer.  The memories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable [AllowDrop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.allowdrop.aspx) on the form and handle the [DragDrop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragdrop.aspx) event. Take a look at the [DragEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.drageventargs.aspx) class for the code for loading a file dropped onto a control.