# Drag & Drop from Windows Explorer into my application’s TextBox

Tags: c#, windows, drag-and-drop, windows-explorer

Why is the dragdrop event never entered?

```
private void textBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    Array a = (Array)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);

    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;
    Debug.WriteLine("were in dragdrop");
}

private void textBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop, false) == true)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you turned the "AllowDrop" property of your text box to "true"? by default its false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the e.Effect assignment to DragDropEffects.Copy.  Double-check that the event assignment is still there, click the lightning bolt icon in the Properties window.  Sample code is available in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68598/how-do-i-drag-and-drop-files-into-a-c-application).  Note that you can cast to string[] directly.

Comment: What If I would set the AllowDrop of the FORM/Window to false but the AllowDrop of the inner TextBox/DAtaGrid in the Form to True, is that working? I do not want to let user drop onto the form, just into the datagrid WITHIN the form.

Comment: yes... but what cast do I have to use to get the File and its real data ? byte[] ?

Comment: You only the get path to the file.  Reading the file requires writing code.  Like File.ReadAllBytes().