# Detect drag outside of application

Tags: c#, windows, drag

How can I detect globally, if something(file, text, image, etc.) is being dragged at the moment? And is there a way to get the data of the object which is being dragged?

Comment: I wonder how can u drag text?

Comment: Is it Win Forms, WPF, or ASP?

Comment: @nuclearsweet You can. Just select the text (for example in you browser), then drag it. It will follow your mouse, you can drop it anywhere which accepts the text dragdrop.

Comment: If you look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you will read that you probably shouldn't do it.. Why do you want that?? Looking [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109269/register-a-global-hook-to-detect-whether-mouse-dragging-files-text) you may or not believe that it isn't even possible.

Comment: @andrei.ciprian This shouldn't matter as the window itself isn't used in the drag process. Maybe I didn't elaborate enough. I want to detect a drag operation globally. e. g. I start draging a file from my desktop and this should trigger something which should say to me that dragging is active.