# Copy file path into clipboard by drag&dropping it into exe file

Tags: drag-and-drop, clipboard, filepath

Is there any possibility to create exe file which copies path of a file into clipboard when you drag&dropp the file into the exe? How could I do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Two ways OTM in Windows:
1. Start > Run
2. Start > Run > "cmd"

in both cases, once you drag the file onto the window, its entire path will be pasted.
To do the copy, you'll have to do that manually (easier in the Run window)

To do this onto an application:
[How do I drag and drop files into an application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68598/how-do-i-drag-and-drop-files-into-a-c-application)

Comment: But my target is to copy the path directly into clipboard and without need to run "cmd". There's already file DropBoxPlugin_v1.4.exe (http://wiki.dropbox.com/DropboxAddons/DropBoxPlugin) doing something like that.

Answer (score 0):

A just found a program called [Copy Path](http://www.rsoftr.com/system-utilities/clipboard-tools/copy_path-91295.html) that works for me. It adds "Copy path" to the Windows Explorer context menu (not exactly drag-and-drop, I know).