# get number of files selected by mouse and throw them to args

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mouse

I want to know how to get number of files selected by mouse and throw it to `args`.
so far I know "`%1`" used to know file path.

```
static void main (string[] args)
{
    string a = args[?] --> number of files selected
}
```

Comment: What are you talking about? Files selected where? In the Windows Explorer?

Comment: You mean files that dragged to window of your application?If u got ur answer so accept the answer.

Comment: yup.. i selected files in the windows explorer, right... then i want to get how many files i selected to my application...

Answer (score 0):

Could you be more specific?

First of all a static void main method is usually reserved for the start point of any .Net application. As explained in MSDN: "The Main method is the entry point of your program, where you create objects and invoke other methods. There can only be one entry point in a C# program."

Hence I find it hard to see how files selected by a mouse would be used here.

The args parameter is used for arguments entered when running the .exe of the application. As explained in MSDN: "The parameter of the Main method is a String array that represents the command-line arguments. Usually you check for the existence of the arguments by testing the Length property"

[Command Line Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb20e19t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

For example: "DoWork.exe foo bar"
In your application will resolve to args[0] = "foo" and args[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb20e19t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) = "bar"

Comment: i selected files on windows explorer, right click the files and choose my application to process those files... but how if i want to tell my application how many files i selected on windows explorer... on command-line arguments i write "C://myapplication.exe" "%1" ...

Answer (score 0):

Number of arguments

```
args.Count()
```

The result for `test.ext 1.txt hello.txt pay.txt` is 3

Go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68598/how-do-i-drag-and-drop-files-into-a-c-application) if you mean manage files that has dragged to the application Window