# drag and drop word file on to windows form

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to drop a word file onto a windows form into a rich text box or text box and have it copy the contents of the word file to the text box?

Comment: Drop from where? Windows explorer? Or word itself?

Comment: .docx or .doc Word file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I drag and drop files into a c# application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68598/how-do-i-drag-and-drop-files-into-a-c-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this documentation on MSDN 'How to: Perform Drag-and-Drop Operations Between Applications': http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2c4z53.aspx

Also: 'Walkthrough: Performing a Drag-and-Drop Operation in Windows Forms': http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/za0zx9y0.aspx