# C# drag and drop files to form

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

How could I load files to a form by drag-and-drop?

Which event will appear?

Which component should I use?

And how to determine name of file and others properties after drag-and-dropping it to a form?

Thank you!

Code

```
   private void panel1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventsArgs e){
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text)){
              e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
              MessageBox.Show(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).toString());
        }
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop)){

        }
   }
```

ok, this works.

How about files? How can I get filename and extension?

and this is only a `dragEnter` action.

Comment: The various drag-related events are all handled together in a coordinated fashion. Have you read the relevant documentation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I drag and drop files into a c# application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68598/how-do-i-drag-and-drop-files-into-a-c-sharp-application)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This code will loop through and print the full names (including extensions) of all the files dragged into your window:

```
if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
{
      string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
      foreach (string filePath in files) 
      {
          Console.WriteLine(filePath);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Check the below link for more info

http://doitdotnet.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/drag-and-drop-files-into-winforms/

```c#
private void Form2_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
    {
      string[] filePaths = (string[])(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop));
      foreach (string fileLoc in filePaths)
        // Code to read the contents of the text file
        if (File.Exists(fileLoc))
          using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(fileLoc))
          {
            MessageBox.Show(tr.ReadToEnd());
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: A summary of the contents of the link is required for a quality answer. And be careful with posting links to your own blog: it looks an awful lot like spam.

Answer (score 4):

You need work with 2 below Events, of course while your Control/Form AllowDrop property's is true.

```
    private void Home_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Link;
        else
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
    }

    private void Home_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {
            string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
            //YourOpenMethod(files);
        }
    }
```

Enjoy...

Comment: I think in this case it's better to use `DragEnter` instead of `DragOver` to save processor time.