# Drag and Drop files in form

Tags: c#, .net

Right now to open a file and load the information in you have to go to "File->open->OK" to open up a file. I want to make it so that you can drag a file from a folder in explorer.exe ad drop it to the form and the program would automatically load the file I dragged and dropped. Any ideas?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Also a duplicate of [C# drag and drop files to form](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8550937/62576). Please do a search here for your question first before asking - `c# drag drop form` would have found both of those duplicates. Searching can get you help faster if the question has already been asked (and answered) before, and it reduces duplication of questions. Thanks.