# Drag and drop files into my listbox

Tags: c#

i try to add the option to my application to drag file into my `Listbox` instead of navigate into the file folder and this is what i have try:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBoxFiles.AllowDrop = true;
    listBoxFiles.DragDrop += listBoxFiles_DragDrop;
    listBoxFiles.DragEnter += listBoxFiles_DragEnter;
}

private void listBoxFiles_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
}

private void listBoxFiles_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    listBoxFiles.Items.Add(e.Data.ToString());
}
```

but instead of the full file path `e.Data.ToString()` `return System.Windows.Forms.DataObject`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This code I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550937/c-sharp-drag-and-drop-files-to-form):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBoxFiles.AllowDrop = true;
    listBoxFiles.DragDrop += listBoxFiles_DragDrop;
    listBoxFiles.DragEnter += listBoxFiles_DragEnter;
}

private void listBoxFiles_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop)) e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
}

private void listBoxFiles_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
    foreach (string file in files)
        listBoxFiles.Items.Add(file);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried using @AsfK's answer in WPF, had to delete

```
listBoxFiles.DragDrop += listBoxFiles_DragDrop;
```

from `public MainWindow()` else I got the dragged files duplicated.

Thanks!