# How can we drag a image from folder to form at run time?

Tags: c#, winforms

currently i am loading a image from button.But now i have to drag a image from folder to the picture box at run time.How can we implement this?

Comment: Maybe these links help you:[Performing Drag-and-Drop Operations in Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984430(v=vs.71).aspx), [How do I drag and drop files into a c# application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68598/how-do-i-drag-and-drop-files-into-a-c-sharp-application)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok.The below code is working fine.

```
 private void pictureBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = null;
            string[] filename = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(filename[0]);
        }
        catch (Exception expr)
        { }
    }
```