# Get File Extension of File Dropped Onto Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

How can I capture the file extension of the file dropped onto a windows form?  For example (pseudocode below)

```
if extension = .xlsx { method1 }
if extension = .txt { method2 }
else { MessageBox.Show("Please drag/drop either a .xlsx or a .txt file"); }
```

Comment: here you can find your answer with a simple google search [Get File Extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) please show a little bit more effort

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I drag and drop files into a C# application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68598/how-do-i-drag-and-drop-files-into-a-c-sharp-application)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to keep in mind that the user can drag *more* than a single file.  Use [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/89470/17034) as a starting point.  First thing you want to do is modify the DragEnter event handler so the user simply can't drop the wrong kind of file at all:

```
    private void Form1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
        if (!e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop)) return;
        string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
        foreach (var file in files) {
            var ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file);
            if (ext.Equals(".xlsx", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ||
                ext.Equals(".txt",  StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) {
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

The DragDrop event handler is much the same, instead of assigning e.Effect you process the file, whatever you want to do with it.