# effect drag and drop file icon on my program effect

Tags: c#, .net, drag-and-drop

How can I achieve the effect of dragging an arbitrary file icon on the icon of my program? That is, I want to make it so that if I drag a file to my program, the program starts and opens this file. In the figure, MyProgram is a program in C # that I write. File is the file I want to open.

[image]

Comment: The default effect of this is that the filename is passed as a command line argument. Check the CommandlineArgs and handle the opening on program start.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I drag and drop files into an application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68598/how-do-i-drag-and-drop-files-into-an-application)

Comment: Hooray! Thanks, it's beautiful! This is what I need! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jens commented you may check `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs` or you can just use main method arguments:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length > 0)
          Console.WriteLine(args[0]); // Here's the file path
}
```